# Synchronising writes into AmazonDB using Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am logging events into two different tables in AmazondDB. The main table is a running log of all events. The summary table has one record per user. Hence , in the summary table I maintain the log of each event in a array. To build the array I select the currect record and append to the end the end of the array.
However,  I observe that sometimes , quite randomly, the lambda updates the main table and not the summary table. What am I doing wrong in not being able to synchronize the two inserts?

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

dynamodb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def add_log(user_id, qset_id, q_no):

    table= dynamodb.Table('SUMMARY_TABLE')
    
    ts = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

    #get item
    try:
        response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'user_id': user_id,
            'qset_id': qset_id
            }
        )
        
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        raise

    # Create the first record if not exists

    if 'Item' not in  response:
        #print('add a new document')
        
        log={'id':1, 'q_no':q_no, 'dt':str(ts)}
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'user_id':user_id,
                'qset_id': qset_id,
                'log': [log],
                'log_id':1,
                'st_date':str(ts) 
            })
    else:
        # Add to the log 

        item = response['Item']
        log_id = item['log_id'] + 1
        st_date = item['st_date'] 
        log={'id':log_id, 'q_no':q_no,'dt':str(ts)}
        
        loglist = item['log']
        loglist.append(log)
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'user_id':user_id,
                'qset_id': qset_id,
                'log': loglist,
                'log_id':log_id,
                'st_date':st_date 
            })
        
        logger.info('## Done Log')
    return


def lambda_handler(event, context):
       
    #data = json.loads(event)
    if 'user_id' in event:
        user_id = event['user_id']
    if 'qset_id' in event:
        qset_id = event['qset_id']

    if 'q_no' in event:
        q_no = event['q_no']   
 
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    

    # Add to main table
    table= dynamodb.Table('MAIN_TABLE') 
    table.put_item(
    Item={
        'user_id': user_id,
        'qset_id': qset_id,
        'q_no':q_no,
        'dt': str(now)
    }
    )
    logger.info('Done Main')

    # Add to summary  table
    add_log(user_id, qset_id, q_no);
       
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,

        'body': json.dumps('Success from API!' )
    }
```

Comment: I've not used python to access DynamoDB, so I'm not sure I can help with this specific problem.  However, I would suggest you take a look at DynamoDB transactions, which can be especially useful when updating state in more than one DynamoDB table.

You could wrap the put_item calls to both tables in a single transaction that either succeeds or fails together.  In that case, you never end up with inconsistent state between the two tables.  You can even include condition checks in the transaction, which would prevent you from having to do a get_item before put_item on the SUMMARY_TABLE

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way of updating an array field. we need to do a couple of programatic manipulations. Otherwise transactions would be ideal